# RxJs: Observable from array of promises

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I am very new to RxJs and the problem I faced looks quite complicated for me. So, I have the following sample code

```
const requests = [...Array(10)].map((_, i) => fetch(`${ ENDPOINT }/${ ++i }`));

from(requests).pipe(
  switchMap(response => response.json()),
  catchError(val => of(val))
).subscribe(value => { ... })
```

I have an array of 10 requests which I would like to process somehow(as an array of resolved Promise values) in my subscribe handler. The example above works just fine when I pass in only one request instead of array, but when it comes to the array I receive

> TypeError: response.json is not a function

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forkJoin`. The important thing here is that in RxJS Promises are always turned into Observables that emit once and then complete. So you don't even need to make any conversion.

```
const requests = [
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.resolve(2),
  Promise.resolve(3),
];

forkJoin(requests).subscribe(console.log);
```

`forkJoin` is typically used with an array of Observables but it works with Promises as well with zero effort.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gcorux

Answer (score 1):

`from` accepts only 1 promise. You can solve it like this:
`from(Promise.all(requests))`

And use `map` instead of `switchMap`. In switchmap you should return another observable, not a value.

```
from(Promise.all(requests)).pipe(
  map(responses => responses.map(response => response.json())),
  catchError(val => of(val))
).subscribe(value => { ... })
```

And don't forget that processing an array of promises will return array of values, so you should not just get a response.json(), but do it for each element in the array

Comment: Note that `response.json()` returns a promise as well, as the response itself is a stream and may not be fully retrieved.

Comment: @backtick And how can I  retrieve exactly the value of resolved Promise in my case?

Comment: Instead of `Promise.all(requests)`, do `Promise.all(requests.map(req => fetch(req).then(res => res.json())))`. That way you're still passing an array of promises to Promise.all, but it will resolve to an array of JSON values instead of an array of responses.

Answer (score 1):

When `from` takes a promise as an argument it just converts it to an observable.

You can return an array of observables instead:

```
const requests = [...Array(10)].map((_, i) => from(fetch(`${ENDPOINT}/${++i}`)));
```

And then get their value by combining the streams, perhaps with `forkJoin`:

```
forkJoin(requests).subscribe(results => console.log(results));
```